# React-native-navigation Change state from another tabnavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation / TabNavigator, is there a way to change the state of a tab from another tab without using Redux or mobx?

Comment: I think not. You need to re-render components in tab and it can't be forced without some action receiver (like `componentWillReceiveProps` in Redux or MobX `@observer`). I was stuck with this issue for a long time when tab navigation needed re-rendering.

Comment: Is there anyway neither if I put the tabs in some of parent component ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can. It is a little complicated, a little hacky and probably has some side-effects but in theory you can do it. I have created a [working example snack here](https://snack.expo.io/BJm8x-0aZ).

In react-navigation you can [set parameters](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#SetParams) for other screens using route's key.

> When dispatching SetParams, the router will produce a new state that
>   has changed the params of a particular route, as identified by the key
>
> - **params** - object - required - New params to be merged into existing route params
> - **key** - string - required - Route key that should get the new params

**Example**

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const setParamsAction = NavigationActions.setParams({
  params: { title: 'Hello' },
  key: 'screen-123',
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(setParamsAction)
```

For this to work you need to know `key` prop for the screen you want to pass parameter. Now this is the place we get messy. We can combine [`onNavigationStateChange`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/#onNavigationStateChange-prevState-newState-action) and [`screenProps`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-options#Screen-Navigation-Options) props to get the current stacks keys and then pass them as a property to the screen we are currently in.

**Important Note:** Because `onNavigationStateChange` is not fired when the app first launched `this.state.keys` will be an empty array. Because of that you need to do a initial navigate action.

**Example**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      keys: []
    };
  }
  onNavigationChange = (prevState, currentState) => {
    this.setState({
      keys: currentState.routes
    });
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <Navigation
        onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationChange}
        screenProps={{keys: this.state.keys}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

And now we can use `keys` prop to get the key of the screen we need and then we can pass the required parameter.

```
class Tab1 extends Component {
  onTextPress = () => {
    if(this.props.screenProps.keys.length > 0) {
      const Tab2Key = this.props.screenProps.keys.find((key) => (key.routeName === 'Tab2')).key;
      const setParamsAction = NavigationActions.setParams({
        params: { title: 'Some Value From Tab1' },
        key: Tab2Key,
      });
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(setParamsAction);
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph} onPress={this.onTextPress}>{`I'm Tab1 Component`}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class Tab2 extends Component {
  render() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{`I'm Tab2 Component`}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{ params ? params.title : 'no-params-yet'}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Now that you can get new parameter from the navigation, you can use it as is in your screen or you can update your state in [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops).

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  const { params } = nextProps.navigation.state;
  if(this.props.navigation.state.params && params &&  this.props.navigation.state.params.title !== params.title) {
    this.setState({ myStateTitle: params.title});
  }
}
```

### UPDATE

Now react-navigation supports listeners which you can use to detect focus or blur state of screen.

> [**addListener**](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) - *Subscribe to updates to navigation lifecycle*
>
> React Navigation emits events to screen components that subscribe to
>   them:
>
> - `willBlur` - the screen will be unfocused
> - `willFocus` - the screen will focus
> - `didFocus` - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
> - `didBlur` - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

*Example from the docs*

```
const didBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'didBlur',
  payload => {
    console.debug('didBlur', payload);
  }
);
// Remove the listener when you are done
didBlurSubscription.remove();

// Payload
{
  action: { type: 'Navigation/COMPLETE_TRANSITION', key: 'StackRouterRoot' },
  context: 'id-1518521010538-2:Navigation/COMPLETE_TRANSITION_Root',
  lastState: undefined,
  state: undefined,
  type: 'didBlur',
};
```

Comment: I tried this but when I swith more than 4 times I'm getting this error message: "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: @rayashi there might be some bug in my example. I was just try to give you an idea of what you can do. The implementation is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand what you want Its how i figure out to refresh prevous navigation screen. In my example I refresh images witch i took captured from camera:

Screen A

```
  onPressCamera() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    navigate('CameraScreen', {
      refreshImages: function (data) {
        this.setState({images: this.state.images.concat(data)});
      }.bind(this),
    });
}
```

Screen B

```
  takePicture() {
   const {params = {}} = this.props.navigation.state;

   this.camera.capture()
     .then((data) => {
       params.refreshImages([data]);
     })
     .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
```